# How does this code extract the max and min from a string of integers?

Tags: python, for-loop, tuples, max, min

This is a solution I found on codewars.com solving for [this kata](https://www.codewars.com/kata/highest-and-lowest).

```
def high_and_low(numbers):
  return " ".join(x(numbers.split(), key=int) for x in (max, min))
```

I do not understand how this solution works, the x function looks like a sort function, so how come OP didn't use sort? Also, how does the for loop on tuple (max,min) extract the max and min? I'm lost. Any examples/links related to this is appreciated too. Thank you for your effort in advance.

Comment: in place of `x()` it puts `max()` and `min()` and it doesn't have to sort it.

Comment: in Python you can assign function name (without `()`) to variable and use this variabla as function. - ie. `show = print` `show("Hello World")` - and `max` `min` are funciton's names - `max(), `min()`

Comment: "in Python you can assign function name (without ()) to variable" wow this is the first time I learned that... Thank you

Comment: BTW: you assign function to variable even in `x(... , key=int)` - you assing function `int()` to variable `key=` and it can later use `key()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the documentation of [max](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max), (and similarly min), `key=int` is used to order the iterable, which in this case is the list of strings you get after doing `numbers.split()`. Then max and min will pick the maximum and minimum integers from the list

`for x in (max, min)` essentially replaces x with the function `max` and `min`

A slightly easier way to do this might be to first extract the list of integers, and then apply max and min on it

```
def high_and_low(numbers):

  nums = list(map(int, numbers.split()))
  return min(nums), max(nums)
```